# Genymotion error in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, genymotion

I've installed earlier Genymotion and my app worked for me on a single device.
But when I've changed the device it gives me some kind of error in Eclipse:

> [2014-02-23 09:43:17 - Speedy] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
>   [2014-02-23 09:43:17 - Speedy] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
>   [2014-02-23 09:43:17 - Speedy] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\Users\AnDrOiD\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.

May someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Genymotion bundles its own adb, which kills the adb Eclipse is trying to use when it starts itself. Go to the adb tab of Genymotion's settings and switch to a custom adb. You'll have to set the SDK path when you do so.

Genymotion's FAQ discusses this a little bit in the question: [How do I automatically connect my virtual device to the ADB tool?](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#collapse-adb).

Answer (score 0):

GenyMotion virtual device work with adb and not as AVD.
Probably is a problem by GenyMotion software. Try to restart it.

Comment: I even restarted the pc but I still keep getting this error