# Android debug bridge is slow

Tags: android, adb, emulation

I am trying to compile my program in android and its not working. The problem is in the "adb". The message which is shown is "The connection to "adb" is slow."

Comment: this problem took my whole day and still its not working

Comment: Any solution to this will be highly appreciated

Comment: Does it say it is slow or "The connection to ADB is DOWN"? I don't see any documentation having ADB being 'slow' as an error. Also edit your question to show whatever error message you have, what software are you using (Eclipse/Android Studio?) and also what system (windows, osx, linux).

Comment: thanks dear the problem is solved .... Actually the problem was that each time i was starting eclipse the emulator Genymotion was already started ... So i closed in and opened it after restarting Eclipse .... :)  Thanks matrixanomaly

Comment: Oh God ! i am again having that problem     #matrixanomaly

Comment: i am using windows 8   this is the error message
"The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question is a little too broad, and from your comments it seems that you sometimes have it working, make sure you follow these steps from the official documentation.

[Click me](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide)

From your comments it looks like once you started eclipse and have adb connected, the server isn't terminating properly. You can also open a new command prompt and run 'adb kill-server' to make sure the connection is properly closed.

Please also check this solution in another SO question that seems to have the same issue as the one you're having: [Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965588/genymotion-error-in-eclipse)

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas good to know, if this question has helped you please mark it as an answer. have a good day!